# Jquery mobile CSS class linking

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am making a mobile webapp with JQuery Mobile. Now at the bottom I have some kind of a navigation menu. Here is the HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-icon="arrow-u"><a href="#top" class="top" data-ajax="false">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="~PROBE(201)~" data-transition="slide">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="~PROBE(208)~" data-transition="slide">Contacten</a></li>
    <li><a href="~PROBE(206)~" data-transition="slide">Klanten</a></li>
    <li><a href="~PROBE(207)~" data-transition="slide">Planning</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want the first listItem at the right side. So I made a css class 'top'

```
.top{
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:35px;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't take this CSS class. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Do you want the list to start from the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try such:

```
ul li a.top{
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:35px;
}
```

OR such:

```
ul li:first-of-type a{
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the `top` class to the `a` intead of the `li`.

**Update**

As your styling gets overridden, you need to increase the [CSS-specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of your selector until it is higher than the specificity of the rule that overrides it. As I don't know much of your DOM, the best I can give you is:

```
ul li.top{
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:35px;
}
```

But that might not be enought. Look through the article on CSS-specificity, there is a part on how to calculate specificity.

Comment: It works just fine in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9tRs/), so there must be something else going on. You will have to troubleshoot a bit more. Does the CSS get applied and then gets overridden, or doesn't it get applied at all? Use the devtools of your browser to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that in certain cases overrides are a bit tricky. You may have to do something like this. Some browsers mobile & web are not picking up the overrides as I would have expected. End result I have to use important to make sure my style gets applied. Just be careful of how use this and where.

```
ul li.top{
    text-align:right !important; 
    padding-right:35px !important;
}
```